# What is an isolated system in capacitive circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, definition, batteries, electronics

Does isolated system here means that the plates of capacitor need not be connected to terminals of a battery?[image]

Answer (score 1):

"Isolated system" means that charge cannot flow into or out of the plates in each dashed box.

That is, the sum of the charges on those plates inside a dashed box cannot change (and we can often assume, given proper initial starting conditions, that this charge sum is 0).

Answer (score 0):

These boxes are nothing important just it is conservation of charges.
By isolated they refer to a system where there is no net gain/loss of charge till establishment of equilibrium.